Webpack issue Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
I'm working on converting my React Native app to support both mobile web and desktop web using react-native-web. I've set up webpack and made necessary changes to my babel.config.js, but I am encountering the following error:
I am getting below error in console of browser and its not loading webpage of app .

webpack://CodeFobe/.…objectSpread2.js?:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at eval (webpack://CodeFobe/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/objectSpread2.js?:2:28)
    at ./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/objectSpread2.js (bundle.js:4369:1)
    at _webpack_require_ (bundle.js:4418:32)
    at fn (bundle.js:4613:21)
    at eval (redux.js:1:671)
    at ./node_modules/redux/es/redux.js (bundle.js:3479:1)
    at _webpack_require_ (bundle.js:4418:32)
    at fn (bundle.js:4613:21)
    at eval (redux-toolkit.esm.js:1:3718)
    at ./node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/redux-toolkit.esm.js (bundle.js:328:1


console error
My Webpack.config.js file:
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './web/index.web.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    clean: true,
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'react-native$': 'react-native-web',
      '@env': path.resolve(__dirname, 'env.web.js'),
    },
    extensions: ['.web.js', '.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.web.ts', '.web.tsx'],
    fallback: {
      crypto: require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
      stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify'),
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(react-native|@react-native|react-native-.|@react-native-.|@babel\/runtime))/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-typescript'],
            plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime'],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: 'images/[name][ext]',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './web/index.html',
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      _DEV_: JSON.stringify(true),
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'),
    }),
    new Dotenv(),
  ],
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    compress: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    port: 3000,
  },
};

babel.config.js
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: [
      'module:metro-react-native-babel-preset',
      '@babel/preset-env',
      '@babel/preset-react',
      '@babel/preset-typescript',
      '@babel/preset-flow',
    ],
    plugins: [
      [
        '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
        {
          regenerator: true,
        },
      ],
      [
        'dotenv-import',
        {
          moduleName: '@env',
          path: (() => {
            const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
            if (env === 'production') {
              return '.env.production';
            } else if (env === 'staging') {
              return '.env.staging';
            } else {
              return '.env.development';
            }
          })(),
          allowlist: [
            'SIZE_MATTERS_BASE_WIDTH',
            'SIZE_MATTERS_BASE_HEIGHT',
            'FB_APP_ID',
            'REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT',
            'ENVIRONMENT',
          ],
          safe: true,
          allowUndefined: false,
        },
      ],
    ],
  };
};

